# ZLib unzip a zip containing multiple files

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, zlib

I am using delphi 7 and need to uncompress a compressed zip file which contains multiple files, I have found examples of how to unzip a single file using ZLib but cannot find any examples of this with muliple files in the zip, would it be possible for someone to either give me an example or point me in the direction of one

thanks

Colin

Comment: `ZLib` <> `Zip`. `ZLib` is a generic data compression library, while `Zip` is a compression and file format library. Just because they both start with `Z` doesn't make them compatible. :) For working with `Zip` files, use a `Zip` library, like `Abbrevia` (mentioned by @ErikKnowles below). If you want to use `ZLib`, you'll have to find a library that wraps it with `Zip-compatible` file I/O anyway, since `ZLib` knows nothing about `Zip` headers and multiple files.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're having problems with zlib, maybe you might want to consider TurboPower's Abbrevia (available on [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpabbrevia/)). With Abbrevia, here's our multiple-file extract code:

```
zip.ArchiveType := atZip ;
zip.ForceType := true ;
zip.OpenArchive({...your .zip archive name});

zip.BaseDirectory :=  {...your extract path...} ;
zip.OnConfirmOverwrite := Overwrite
zip.ExtractFiles('*');
```

There's options to handle extraction failure, confirmation of overwrites, etc. It's a pretty nice library to work with, and it's free.

Answer (score 2):

There is an example in the zlib source distribution on [zlib.net](http://zlib.net/).  Take a look at [contrib/minizip/miniunz.c](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/contrib/minizip/miniunz.c) .